# Importing RecyclerView not working even WITH import statement

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-recyclerview

I'm having an issue where I copy-pasted some files from an existing Android Studio project into a new project.

The project I copy pasted from uses a RecyclerView (and imports it via `import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;`and that works perfectly in that project.

However, that exam same line in my new project gives a `Cannot resolve symbol 'recyclerview'` error.

I'm lost on what I can do to fix this. I've tried invalidating caches and restarting but that didn't fix anything. I've seen other questions on this topic but they all forgot to add an import statement. In my case, I have a perfectly functioning project but that line of code simply isn't working once copied over to my new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are missing the dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    // implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc03"
}
```

Comment: Where do I add this? In my Build.gradle file?

Comment: Yes, on the module level, not the root project.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. It seems Gradle doesn't add that dependency for code that was pasted in.